# Spring data jpa nested object How to define complex query Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Fake code

```
 public class User{

      private long id;

      private String name;

      @OneToMany

      private List<Address>address;



        // ......set get

}
```

```
public class Address{

      private long id;

      private String name;

      private Integer isDel



        // ......set get

}
```

> How should the interface be named? Sql is as follows.

select * from user u

left join user_address ua  on u.id = ua.user_id

left join address a on ua.address_id = a.id

where u.name = 'xxx' and a.name='xxxxx' and a.is_del=0

```
interface MyRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {

  List<User> ???();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select distinct u from User u, Address a " + 
         "where a member of u.address and " + 
         "u.name=:userName and " + 
         "a.name=:addressName and " + 
         "a.isDel=:isDel")
  List<User> getUsers(@Param("userName") String userName, 
                      @Param("addressName") String addressName, 
                      @Param("isDel") Integer isDel);
}
```